# What's the solution of this Raven's matrix? (2)

Tags: pattern, visual

here's another matrix which I don't understand:

[image]

What's the solution and why?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right, it is a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> The top right option

Because

> There are 3 types of shapes. The circle (top center), triangle (center), and square with the top missing (middle right). There are two other variations of these. One where the left and right half is swapped (middle left, top right, and top left), and one where the right half is rotated 180 degrees (bottom left and bottom center). We are missing the second variation of the square.

Comment: I see it now, the top right one deceived me since I was seeing the triangle with the top part upside down instead of the two half swapped